# Can't create MVC4 controller for classes with a base class (Generated from Entity Framework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 5 with MVC4 to create a small test-app using Model First.

I have two projects, a `data` project, and a `ui` project which references data.

I have my model `MYModel.edmx` in `data` which has the following entity's

`[ITEM] 
    [BOOK][DVD]`

Where "book" and "dvd" have a base type of the abstract class "Item".

Using the code-generation, it creates the classes for these 3 tables and my dbContext as so:

`public DbSet<Item> Items {get;set;}`

Not creating any DbSet for accessing "Books" or "DVDs".

IF I try to create a new controller using my data context and a model class of "Books" I get the following error

`mynamespace.data.books is not part of the specified mynamespace.data.dbcontext class, and the mynamespace.data.dbcontext class could not be modified to add a dbset<mynamespace.data.books> property to it. (For example )`

What is the correct way to go about using EF with base types and model first as I am clearly doing something wrong, should I even be using Model first? Would it be easier to use Code first for this scenario and create the DBContext myself?

Comment: Are you creating your models and also generating your entities via your edmx? It should be one or the other.

Comment: @ChrisHardie All generated by EDMX

Comment: And your abstract class is being generated by the EDMX?

Comment: @ChrisHardie Yes, In the property window for my "Item" entity, I have set it as Abstract = true. It generates a `public abstract partial class Item` from the EDMX (In the .tt code generation item)

Comment: Sounds like you are implementing Table-Per-Hierarchy inheritance. If you look at your actual database structure, there will only be an Item table, but it will contain fields for Books and DVDs. I'm not familiar with doing it model-first, but you should check this out: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not terribly familiar with model-first, but try adding this in your `mynamespace.data` namespace:

```
public class DVD : Item{
    //Put your DVD specific properties here
}

public class Book : Item{
     //Put your Book specific properties here
}
```

Don't add primary keys here, they will both inherit the ItemId primary key, because in the database both DVD and Book are being stored in the Item table.

Then, add the two models to your context:

```
public DbSet<DVD> DVDs {get;set;}
public DbSet<Book> Books {get;set;}
```

A good reference to implementing Table-Per-Hierarchy via code-first can be found here, I'm sorry i don't know of any model-first reference: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I ended up removing my EDMX and going for code-first instead as it seemed to work better. The code generated by the EDMX isn't brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem, but I don't know what causes it. All you need to do is:

1. Compile the project
2. Right click your Controllers folder to add your controller
3. In Data Context class, Add Controller dialog box, manually type your context, and click Add

Hope it help